# $watch not trigger when i use ng-click in element using angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have used $watch for scope variable `"active"` to watch the changes. also have use `ng-click="toggleTab()"` in the child element. now I try to watch the scope changes when I clicked that child element. but it's working in locally. but not work in life. `ng-click` only working. code is below

```
<uib-tabset type="tabs" active="active">
  <uib-tab index="0" heading="Advertisers" ng-click="toggleTab($event, 'advertisers', '0');">
```

**controller:**

```
$scope.$watch('active', function(next, prev) {
  $scope.submitted = false;
  angular.element('#advertisers .tags .input').val('');
  nextTabIndex = next;
  prevTab = prev;
});
$scope.toggleTab = function() {});
```

Answer (score 0):

Where in this code it's shown that you change `active`?
It's a variable that you watch after all.

You also have a problem with `toggleTab` function. You sent 3 parameters but the function you specified uses none.

There is also a possibility that active is an array or object (in this case you have written active condition wrong since arrays basically are objects in JS and objects are always truthy. Also, in this case, you need to deep-watch by adding an additional (3rd parameter in after the callback function with a value of true like:

```
$scope.$watch('active', callback, true);
```

As it stands now your code is not written to work as you want it to work. It's also hard to understand exactly what you want but if you simply want to see `$watch()` in action, change the value of `active`. You can simply state `ng-click="active=active+1"`. This is I think the simplest way you can see it go off from this code.

So everything stays the same but you have this instead your HTML element:

```
<uib-tab index="0" heading="Advertisers" ng-click="active=active+1">
```

Comment: Thanks for you response. i got some idea from you suggestion. let me check with that